# How to prevent XSS injection while allowing users to post external images

Tags: security, csrf, xss

A user recently reported to me that they could exploit the BBCode tag [img] that was available to them through the forums.

`[img=http://url.to.external.file.ext][img]`

Of course, it would show up as a broken image, however the browser would retrieve the file over there. I tested it myself and sure enough it was legit.

I'm not sure how to prevent this type of XSS injection other than downloading the image and checking if it is a legitimate image through PHP. This easily could be abused with a insanely huge file.

Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: Require images use a specific service, like imgur?

Comment: No, they can link any hosted image on the internet.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139083/remote-image-embeds-how-to-handle-ones-that-require-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could request the headers and check if the file is actually an image.

**Edit:**

Sorry that I couldn't answer in more depth; I was enjoying dinner.

There are two ways I see it:

1. You check to see if the supplied address is actually a image when the post is submitted or viewed, you could accomplish this by checking the headers (making sure it's actually an image) or by using file extension. This isn't fool-proof and has some obvious issues (changing the image on the fly, etc.).
2. Secure your site that even if there is a compromise with the [img] tag there is no real problem, for example: the malicious code can't use stolen cookies.
3. Use a script that requests an external image and modifies the headers.

A basic way to check the remote files content type:

```
$Headers = get_headers('http://url.to.external.file.ext');
if($Headers[8] == 'text/html') {
    echo 'Wrong content type.';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Worked something out:

`function lolfy($url) {
 $head = get_headers($url);
  if ($head['Content-Type'] == "image/jpeg" || $head['Content-Type'] == "image/x-png" || $head['Content-Type'] == "image/gif")
  {
   return $url;
  }
  else {
   return "boken";
  }
 }`

Comment: However, I realized that the server I am requesting the information from could easily spoof the content type when only I am requesting it. I don't think this is a safe approach.

Comment: Use a script to request the external image but modify the headers yourself. For example: http://www.abdulqabiz.com/files/proxy.php.txt

Comment: "Secure your site that even if there is a compromise with the [img] tag there is no real problem..." I think this is the best you can do. The others can be spoofed.

Answer (score 2):

There's only two solutions to this problem. Either download the image and serve from your webserver, or only allow a white-list of url patterns for the images.

Some gotchas if you decide to download the images -

1. Make sure you have a validation for the maximum file size. There are ways to stop the download if the file exceeds a certain size, but these are language specific.
2. Check that the file is actually an image.
3. If you store it on the hard-disk, be sure to rename it. You shouldn't allow the user to control the file name on the system.
4. When you serve the images, use a throw-away domain, or use naked ip address to serve the images. If the browser is ever tricked in thinking the image is executable code, the same-origin policy will prevent further damage.